# Is there a pattern in spring which allows to use data from remote server in several services without requesting it many times?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I'm  trying to create CRUD endpoints for entity **A**. This entity has a field with collection of **ids** of another entity **B**. Entity **B** lives on **remote server**.

I want to

1. Validate that entities **B** with passed **ids** actually exists on **remote server**.
2. Save in local database both fields of entities **B**: **id** and **name**

**name** of entity **B** can be received from **remote server** via **endpoint**. And via this **endpoint** I can validate that entities **B** with passed **ids** exists on **remote server**.

In my app I tried to separate the logic, so there is one spring component for validating entity **B** and other for mapping from DTO representation of entity **A** to internal representation.

And I need to call **remote server** with the same request for both purposes: for validation of existence and for mapping with **id** and **name** on entity **B**.

I have an idea with short time cache, but it seem odd to me to use cache for such purpose.

Other way is to call this **endpoint** in some upper service and pass received data to validator and to mapper, but with such implementation upper service need to know this internal details of validator and mapper (that they need information from **remote server**)

Is there an other way around to do it with spirng?

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial

Comment: Why does it seem odd to use caching? Storing data in memory to avoid repeating expensive operations. That's a classic case where caching *may* be of help. Or you can design your code to get the data once per call. I don't know what you're talking about internal details of validator and mapper, but the code can be designed properly too.

Comment: Caching seems odd to me, because this data is needed only in context of one request.
Yes, question just about that, how to design code to fit described requirements

Comment: If the data is used for only one request, then what good is caching? A cache only improves performance when the cached data is read multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with request scoped cache.

Here is the example, which I found: https://medium.com/@james.tran/memoize-part-1-request-level-cache-for-spring-applications-the-why-and-the-how-75877d8999ea